# adding input format for CCK fields in drupal

Tags: 6, entities, input-formats

Is there any way by which I can add a input format for the CCK added Text Fields ?
By default its only there for Body field in any node/add , I want this for other fields to evaluate PHP Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi line text fields switch to *filtered text*. For single line text fields the answer is no.

Comment: Yes I was referring to text areas.